# How to make a Lottie animation responsive to a user action?

Tags: android, animation, lottie

Is there a way to make Lottie animation responsive to user action?

i.e.: we have two shapes, shape A is morphing its bounds, shape B is moving by some closed path. the user does drag, shape B must stop it's moving and start moving to shape B depending on user movement. on some distance from shape A, shape B must start morphing it's bound and try to magnetize to shape A changing its bounds.

Comment: If you try create a game - use SurfaceView - it's provides smallest time between each frame.

Comment: no, we have complex animation which should be kind of responsive to user actions :/

Comment: I believe that there is no possibility to have full control over animation. You could start animation on some user action, but after you start it you couldn't control it frame by frame.

Answer (score 0):

Install Adobe After Effect CC above 2015 and Adobe Illustrator CC for creating vectors and paths.

And Install the [ZXP installer](http://zxpinstaller.com/) and the  [BodyMovin Extension](https://aescripts.com/bodymovin/).

And start with the basics of paths. Try making the paths and shape morphing. You can't drag the shapes basically. But you can surely change the shapes of A and B. Wish they work on user interaction in the future versions.